# Using ProgressDialog with Thread on Android throws ViewRoot$CalledWrongFromThreadException

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to show Progress Dialog while filling layout:

EDIT (here is the code):

```
public class CalendarMonth extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

        private int mMonth = 0;
    private int mYear = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar_m);

        filterData();
    }

    private void filterData() {

        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading calendar", 
                "Please wait...", true, true);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();

        new GenerateMonth().execute();
    }

class GenerateMonth extends AsyncTask {
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            generateMonth();
            return true;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }

    private void generateMonth() {

        mCalendar = new CalendarInstance(mMonth, mYear);

        mMonth = this.mCalendar.getSelectedMonth();
        mYear = this.mCalendar.getSelectedYear();

        TextView monthName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthName);
        monthName.setText(mCalendar.getMonthAndYearAsString());

        Button monthPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.monthPrevious);
        monthPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int month = mMonth - 1;
                int year = mYear;
                if (mMonth == 1) {
                    month = 12;
                    year = mYear - 1;
                }
                mMonth = month;
                mYear = year;
                filterData();
            }
        });

        Button monthNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.monthNext);
        monthNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int month = mMonth + 1;
                int year = mYear;
                if (mMonth == 12) {
                    month = 1;
                    year = mYear + 1;
                }
                mMonth = month;
                mYear = year;
                filterData();
            }
        });

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setNumColumns(7);
        gridview.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        gridview.setAdapter(new CalendarMonthAdapter(this, mMonth, mYear));     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        filterData();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it might be easier to use an AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

so you would have something like this

```
public class Temp extends Activity {
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.temp);


        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Filter", "blah", true, true);
        mDialog.show();
        new FillDataTask.execute();

    }


    class FillDataTask extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

             try {
                    filterData();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("FILTER", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return true;  // you can return whatever you want here
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            //update progressDialog here
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT BELOW

do it like this

```
public class CalendarMonth extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

        private int mMonth = 0;
    private int mYear = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar_m);

        filterData();
    }

    private void filterData() {

        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading calendar", 
                "Please wait...", true, true);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();

        new GenerateMonth().execute();
    }

    private void genMonth()
    {

        mCalendar = new CalendarInstance(mMonth, mYear);

        mMonth = this.mCalendar.getSelectedMonth();
        mYear = this.mCalendar.getSelectedYear();

    }

    private void layoutUI()
    {
          TextView monthName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthName);
        monthName.setText(mCalendar.getMonthAndYearAsString());

        Button monthPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.monthPrevious);
        monthPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int month = mMonth - 1;
                int year = mYear;
                if (mMonth == 1) {
                    month = 12;
                    year = mYear - 1;
                }
                mMonth = month;
                mYear = year;
                filterData();
            }
        });

        Button monthNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.monthNext);
        monthNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int month = mMonth + 1;
                int year = mYear;
                if (mMonth == 12) {
                    month = 1;
                    year = mYear + 1;
                }
                mMonth = month;
                mYear = year;
                filterData();
            }
        });

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setNumColumns(7);
        gridview.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        gridview.setAdapter(new CalendarMonthAdapter(this, mMonth, mYear)); 
    }
}
}

class GenerateMonth extends AsyncTask {
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            genMonth();
            return true;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            layoutUI();
            mDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but when I use this code RuntimeException is thrown :(

Comment: can you post your code and the error, are you doing anything with the UI in the doBackground function? if so you shouldn't do anything with the UI there, wait until you get to the onPostExecute function to do anything UI

Comment: Post `filterData()` so we can help.

Comment: I have deleted some methods which causes ParseExcption...you can see my code above.

Comment: it looks like you are doing A LOT of stuff on the UI thread in the "doInBackground" method, you can't and shouldn't do UI operations in that method, move these things to the onPostExecute method

for example: monthName.setText(mCalendar.getMonthAndYearAsString());
monthPrevious.setOnClickListener, gridview.setNumColumns(7);
        gridview.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
        gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        gridview.setAdapter(new CalendarMonthAdapter(this, mMonth, mYear));

These are all UI operations, move those to the onPostExecute method

Comment: Well I need to generate layout while the dialog is show. When layout is generates, dialog should be dismissed...CalendarMonthAdapter() generates most of the layout...

Comment: look at my edits above, follow like that , i took the ui tasks out of the background work and moved them to the postExecute

Comment: I've tried it before, but it didn't work...layout was generated and then Dialog was shown :(

Comment: please be more specific, how and why did it not work? what was wrong with the layout ? What is bad about "layout was generated then Dialog was shown" ? Did you get any errors, what were they (stacktraces please)?

Comment: nothing is wrong (no exception, but how it's working)...so I press tab called "Month", then there is a slight delay, then layout of calendar is generated and then Dialog is shown and never dismissed. I wanted to fill that delay with Dialog and after generating the layout, Dialog shold have been dismissed (sry for my english :-)).

Comment: Is there any possibility how to generate layout "in background" on Android?

Answer (score 0):

The error must be in filterData, if you are updating the UI from filter data it will give that exception. I would recomend using async task, using doInBackground to build the data, and onPostExecute to update the UI.

Comment: I'm using BaseAdapter which builds a Gridview of Button. I want to dismiss Dialog when the GridView is built. I have tried to use Asynctask (the one sim has posted), but I get RuntimeException

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is in generateMonth function, which is invoked from the doInBackground function. You should not access UI from doInBackground function or from any function called from doInBackground. This function is aimed to do tasks that require lot of time, like calculations or complex DB queries, but MUST NOT access UI. Your UI updates should be done in function onPostExecute. So, things like:

> gridview.setNumColumns(7)

are not allowed in doInBackground (or generateMonth which is invoked from there).